# Is it possible to reference similar SQL column names from joined tables using PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have a few tables joined together, but several of the columns have similar names. I'm using php to fetch those values, but I am unable to use the sql identifier in php to pick the correct column... i.e. in SQL I have two tables Register and Jurisdict. both of them have a column called "name". in SQL I can reference these columns as such

```
r.name
j.name
```

and these would give me values from the two different tables. However in I PHP am not able to use the r. or j. and anytime I use name it returns which ever table is selected first in the SQL statement.

Here is my current code

```
<?php


    $sql = "
SELECT j.rpt_name, r.name 
FROM [SMARTCM] . [dbo] . [REGISTER] r

join [SMARTCM] . [dbo] . [jurisdict] j
on j.UniqueKey = r.FK_JURSDICT_KEY

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );

?>
```

I'm using a while loop to generate the PHP, with this tag to reference the column

```
<?php echo $row['name']; ?>
```

However it breaks if I try and use the table reference (r.name) like i would i sql

Comment: Supply an alias to one of the columns, `select j.name as jname`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use aliasing feature of SQL query..

```
<?php


    $sql = "
SELECT j.name as j_name, r.name as r_name 
FROM [SMARTCM] . [dbo] . [REGISTER] r

join [SMARTCM] . [dbo] . [jurisdict] j
on j.UniqueKey = r.FK_JURSDICT_KEY";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );


echo $row['j_name'];

echo $row['r_name'];
?>
```

Comment: boom! just like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shared the code involved in row retrieval but I presume it's using `sqlsrv_fetch_array()`. If you look at the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php) you'll see it has a parameter called `$fetchType`:

> array sqlsrv_fetch_array ( resource $stmt [, int $fetchType [, int $row [, int $offset ]]] )
>
> ### fetchType
>
> A predefined constant specifying the type of array to return. Possible
>   values are `SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC`, `SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC`, and
>   `SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH` (the default).

... and then the important bit:

> **A fetch type of `SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC` should not be used when consuming a result set with multiple columns of the same name.**

So you have to choose:

- Have dupe names and retrieve stuff from numeric arrays (`SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC`)
- Get unique names so you can use associative arrays

  ```
  SELECT j.name AS j_name, r.name AS r_name
  ```

Last but not least, array contents (or any other PHP variable) should never be a mystery to you. Please have a look at [var_dump()](http://php.net/var_dump).

Comment: you are correct, I am using sqlsrv_fetch_array. Thank you for the detailed response, I'm still learning a great deal about how PHP works and appreciate all the information you've provided. assigning aliases to the column names seems to do the job.

Are you saying that I should use a var_dump to see what column names are being returned to be from my fetch array?

Comment: Yes, you can use `var_dump()` as helper tool **during development** (not in final code). I mentioned that because "am not able to use the r. or j" suggested you could be trying out key names. BTW, `SELECT ... AS` is SQL, a different language that's not related to PHP.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Yes I'm currently at a point in my learning where I'm trying to find the best ways for SQL (whether it be MySQL or MSSQL or whatever) to interface with PHP.